# Resetting Standard output Stream

Tags: java, io

I know that there is a function in Java to set Standard Output Stream to any user defined value using `System.setOut` method..

But is there any method to reset the standard output to the one which was stored earlier or the one which is standard output?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can get hold of the file descriptor for standard out through [`FileDescriptor.out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html#out). To reset standard out to print to console, you do

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
```

Another way is to simply hold on to the original object, as follows:

```
PrintStream stdout = System.out;
System.setOut(new PrintStream(logFile));

// ...

System.setOut(stdout);                   // reset to standard output
```

Answer (score 26):

This is an old question, but it turns up in Google search all the time and I wanted to correct it.  You can actually get it, by using the [`FileDescriptor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) class.  Calling `new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)))` should give you something which prints to stdout.

```
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;


public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.err.println("error.");
    System.out.println("out.");
    System.setOut(System.err);
    System.out.println("error?");
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
    System.out.println("out?");
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify if the accepted answer is incorrect (i.e. if `System.setOut(stdout);` works as expected)?  Is there a benefit to your method vs. simply storing the original stream?  Also, I notice `System.out` and the like are all marked `final`, curious if you can offer any insight into how Java handles `setOut()` under the covers.

Comment: `System.out` and `System.err` are handled by the underlying native C code. They are marked as `final` so that their pointer values are not changed without the native part of the VM "noticing it". The provided `setOut()` method is required to let the native part adjust its internal references.