# Java BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter) not detecting output closed (eg. manylines | java ... | head -3)

Tags: java

I am wanting to write a filter program that will read gigabytes of lines (logs) on stdin, and write lines to stdout, but so far I'm getting stuck making it stop when its output get closed.

In the following invocation, the java process is not terminating when `head -3` completes and closes its input. I see the first three lines get emitted, and then it hangs (presumably until the `zcat | java` part completes, which it does).

```
zcat blah/*.gz | java -cp . LikeCat | head -3
```

I want it to behave like the following, where the whole pipeline closes down when `head` completes.

```
zcat blah/*.gz | cat | head -3
```

For comparison (I had done this largely as a performance comparison when figuring out the best way to read lines from stdin in Java), I have the following Python, which works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print line
```

But my Java foo is apparently too noobish. This is what I have so far. No exception gets printed. Performance with well over 1 million lines is equivalent to the Python code so far (little disappointing perhaps, but is out of scope for this question).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class LikeCat
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        String line;

        try {
            while ( (line = in.readLine()) != null ) {
                out.write(line);
                out.newLine();
                // out.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Running it through strace, I see that it the write system call return -1 and errno is EPIPE, as expected, but looking at the documentation I expected an IOException to be raised. Still in strace, I see it go back to reading from stdin. Looking closer, it does look up some locale data, so is presumably responding to some sort of event, but no sign of any exception.

```
[pid 22649] read(0, ONE
"ONE\n", 8192)      = 4
[pid 22649] write(1, "ONE\n", 4ONE
)        = 4
[pid 22649] read(0, TWO
"TWO\n", 8192)      = 4
[pid 22649] write(1, "TWO\n", 4TWO
)        = 4
[pid 22649] read(0, THREE
"THREE\n", 8192)    = 6
[pid 22649] write(1, "THREE\n", 6)      = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
[pid 22649] --- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=22648, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 22649] open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
[pid 22649] read(4, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2502
[pid 22649] read(4, "", 4096)           = 0
[pid 22649] open("/usr/share/locale/en_NZ.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 22649] open("/usr/share/locale/en_NZ.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 22649] open("/usr/share/locale/en_NZ/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 22649] open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 22649] open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 22649] open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 22649] read(3, "PK\3\4\n\0\0\10\0\0i\n\206J\34&\t\276\266\1\0\0\266\1\0\0$\0\0\0", 30) = 30
[pid 22649] read(3, "\312\376\272\276\0\0\0004\0\31\n\0\5\0\24\t\0\4\0\25\n\0\5\0\26\7\0\27\7\0\30\1"..., 438) = 438
[pid 22649] write(1, "THREE\n", 6)      = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
[pid 22649] --- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=22648, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 22649] read(0,
```

Looking at the documentation for BufferedWriter, it returns void, so its not a case of checking for a return-code, and there is no method I could find for asking "are you still open?".

No IOException is raised until I ^C it.

This is Oracle Java 1.8 on Linux.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b31)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b31, mixed mode)
```

Appreciate your help,
Cheers,
Cameron

### Update 1: Calling System.out.checkError() regularly

Thanks to @EJP for pointing out the System.out is a PrintStream which swallows exceptions and that I need to run System.out.checkError() regularly.

From the documentation for System.out.checkError()

> public boolean checkError() Flushes the stream and checks its error
>   state. The internal error state is set to true when the underlying
>   output stream throws an IOException other than InterruptedIOException,
>   and when the setError method is invoked. [...].
>
> Returns: true if and only if this stream has encountered an IOException other
>   than InterruptedIOException, or the setError method has been invoked

That works, but its annoying because its flushing the output every time if I put it in the loop.

I understand it wants to answer the question "did you manage to write all that data?", but I'm more interested in "did you by chance happen to find your output got closed?"

If I use 'System.out.checkError()' occassionally (like, every 100th line of input), then by program will be slow to quit --- which is potentially an annoying thing if the program is part of some larger pipeline.

And if I use 'System.out.checkError()' on every iteration, I get an insufferable performance penalty due to checkError() flushing output on every iteration.

By C background makes me think the key takeaway here is "don't use System.out, but instead use the raw filedescriptor underneath that".

### Update 2: Do away with PrintStream  (faulty implementation, but getting closer)

(I have removed this to prevent promulgation of what was a bad idea.)

### Update 3: Create a new FileOutputStream based on FileDescriptor.out (seems to work nicely; review needed)

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339512/1002016, I was able to determine that yes, I can create a object (akin to System.out) but based on a the file-descriptor (actually FileDescriptor). Use FileDescriptor.out to get on object representing a file-descriptor corresponding to stdout, then go through a FileOutputStream and OutputStreamWriter and then BufferedWriter.

... (not trying to troll, but why is this more painful than `FILE *out = fdopen(2)`)

Here's my code as it now stands. It will catch IOException, but as yet it doesn't do anything to determine if it was due to Broken pipe.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class LikeCat
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
        String line;

        try {
            while ( (line = in.readLine()) != null ) {
                out.write(line);
                out.newLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        finally {
            try { out.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No you don't. You have an `OutputStreamWriter` based on an `OutputStream` that is still in reality a `PrintStream` and that therefore still swallows exceptions. Repeated here for clarity so as not to allow future readers to be misled.

Comment: I've struck out the mis-steps, and have found a better way, using FileDescriptor.out

Comment: I would just remove the 'mis-steps' altogether. No point in leaving them lying around to confuse people.

Comment: Neither `cat` nor your Java process “detects” when `head -3` is finished reading.  Imagine if your command were `zcat blah/*.gz | java -cp . LikeCat > /dev/null`;  would you expect intermediate commands to cease writing just because the output is going to /dev/null?  `head` simply consumes all of the output, while displaying only the first three lines.

Comment: @VGR. That's not true; if it were, you couldn't do `infinitely-long-output | head -1` and have it stop. What happens is that `head` exits, and by doing so it closes its stdin (well, the filedescriptor) which is connected to the stdout of the Java process (or cat, etc.), so that file-descriptor gets closed. Java (/cat/etc.) then goes to to use the write(2) system-call, and the OS responds with an error (-1, and sets the global variable errno to EPIPE). If it tries again, then it gets the SIGPIPE signal.

Comment: @VGR To further clarify, writing to /dev/null is very different than writing to a closed filedescriptor. (you just end up writing to something that behaves like a file stream, and it gets thrown away).

Comment: @VGR No it doesn't. It reads the correct number of lines and then exits, which will cause an upstream EPIPE. It does not behave like `/dev/null`. Check the source code. I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream`, and `PrintStream` swallows exceptions. You need to call `System.out.checkError()` regularly.

Comment: Thank you; that at least gets it working. I've updated my question with some follow-up concerns.

Comment: @CameronKerr All you need to do now is find a value of 'regularly' that suits you, somewhere between 'slow to quit' and 'insufferable performance'. Only you know that that can be.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I figured out a nicer way (cast the System.out to an OutputStream when passing it into OutputStreamWriter().

Comment: @CameronKerr That will have exactly no effect whatsoever.