# How to copy run console log to a file in talend open studio?

Tags: console, log4j, talend

how to get conlsoe data using tjava or log4j in TOS?

if anyone know this please share your ideas
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vvBu.png

Comment: Hi and Welcome. To improve your experience on SO please take the tour, read how to ask and how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: try using a tLogCatcher or a tFlowMeterCatcher components

Comment: https://community.talend.com/s/article/Log-j-tips-and-tricks-I8730?language=en_US will show how to add an Log4J RollingFileAppender appender to your project setting t o store everything in a file.

Answer (score 1):

What I do at the beginning of the job (tPrejob) in a tJava:

```
/* keep stdout */
globalMap.put("stdout",System.out);
/* send output to file */
java.io.File outputFile = new java.io.File("/log-template.txt");
System.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream(outputFile, false), true));
```

And at the end in tJava (tPostjob), it's optional—but, in my case, necessary because I don't need to put everything:

```
/* restore default stdout */
System.setOut((java.io.PrintStream)globalMap.get("stdout"));
```

Sources:

- https://community.talend.com/s/feed/0D73p000004kWwdCAE?language=en_US
- [Resetting Standard output Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339499/resetting-standard-output-stream/5339512#5339512)